# Class not Found in PHP PDO FetchAll FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I want to Create an beginners php oop script with an shop database.

Until i have create a Category Class, a main.php script and a dbCon.php Script. The main script includes the database connection and should create some category classes with the pdo fetch class statement -> so the plan...

No comes my problem:
the main.php cant find the category class and my script stops with an fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Core\Category' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 10

Here is my main.php

```
<?php
    namespace Core;
    use PDO;

    include "dbCon.php";

    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM s_categories");
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"Core\\Category");
?>
```

and here my category class:

```
class Category
{
    private $cid;
    private $cmsText;
    private $aid = [];
    private $id;
}
```

since both files are in the same namespace the main.php should find the category class, right?

Comment: No, __wrong__. You don't include file with class. Neither you have autoloader.

Comment: Just like you had to include dbCon.php you have to include the Category class file, or autoload it.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks <3

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks <3